# Unexpexted { error in PHP even though all brackets are checked

Tags: php

I am doing some PHP coding. And in that I am getting error Unexpected `{` for this part of code:

```
function image_filenames($dir){
    $handle = @opendir($dir) or die("I cannot open the directory '<b>$dir</b>' for reading.");
    $images = array();

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
           if (eregi('\.(jpg|gif|png)$', $file){
              $images[] = $file;
           }
    }

    closedir($handle);
    return $images;
}
```

The error is given specifically for the `{` in `if (eregi('\.(jpg|gif|png)$', $file){` line.
 If I comment this function, the page loads perfectly fine.

What I am missing?

Comment: use some IDE like netbeans or php storm and you will not have such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed one more ')'

```
   if (eregi('\.(jpg|gif|png)$', $file)){
```

Comment: Thanks man, did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

A simple typo:

You are having a parse error in your code.

Observe the missing brace:

Change

```
if (eregi('\.(jpg|gif|png)$', $file){
```

To:

```
if (eregi('\.(jpg|gif|png)$', $file)){
```

Comment: True!! Silly mistake.. Thanks for the explanation